# mac, java 1.5: javax.mail not recognized as a jar file

Tags: java, jar, email

hello fellow java developers,

Having a little issue with creating a java application on a macintosh computer (snow leopard).

I've set up my application in eclipse, added all of the appropriate jar files, but for some reason the code is not recognizing some of my variables as valid types.

I've imported the libraries via

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
```

These libraries are not recognized by the application.  BUT I've put them on the build path!  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: got it - I had 2 versions of the api on the classpath

Answer (score 2):

Its an extra package for Java SE. 
Download from [here](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/)

Answer (score 1):

Java Mail Api you have to download from [here](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) and then add that jar to your eclipse project by following [these instruction](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29). If it wont work please post some more details how you added jar to your project.